# svg create circles

Tags: svg

I am new to svg and dont know its structure.I want to create 10 circle in random positions.How can I do this inside a loop like for()  loop ?

```
<g id="rotateSquare">
 <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="goldenrod" />
<text x="110" y="52" fill="red">10</text>
<animateTransform
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="rotate"
    from="0,150,150" to="360,150,150"
    begin="0s" dur="1s"
    repeatCount="1"/>
```

Comment: Is your svg in embedded in some sort of HTML document? Are you able to use external scripts? You might want to add more specifics to your question.

Comment: My document is SVG and some HTML code are embedded into SVG.Also I can only use Javascript(no JQuery).Can I use HTML for the loop?

Comment: See http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml for an example of procedurally creating SVG elements and adding them to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 
   var new_circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
```

then after you set the attributes, (cx,cy,r can be randomly generated via a function),
you can insert the new node you created into the svg document:

```
   /*parent elemnt*/.appendChild(new_circle);
```

You can place this function into a loop and generate as many circles as you want. You could even randomize the colors!

Comment: I understood the logic thank you.But I am not sure how I will insert the new node into svg after declared the features.Do I need to create another method to insert into svg?

Comment: @Ecrin Your comment is answered already. See `appendChild` above.